# Wrong characters for accented words when converting from PDF to PCL with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript

I'm trying to convert some PDF files (generated with FastReports) to PCL, using Ghostscript, and it works nice, except that the words with accents show wrong characters.

This is how I call ghostscript:

```
bin\gswin32c -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pxlmono -sFONTPATH=C:\Windows\Fonts -dDuplex -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=2 -sOutputFile=Parte.pcl -fParte.pdf
```

This is my original PDF: 
[image]

This is the result PCL:
[image]

I guess the problem are the fonts, because it says it can't find the fonts Arial and Verdana (although both are installed on \Windows\Fonts).

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.27 (2019-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 2.
Page 1
Can't find CID font "Verdana".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Verdana, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-Identity" is not provided either. attempting to use fallback CIDFont.See doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from %rom%Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Identity ... Done.
Can't find CID font "Verdana".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Verdana, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Can't find CID font "Verdana".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Verdana, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Can't find CID font "Arial".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Arial, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Can't find CID font "Arial".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Arial, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Page 2
Can't find CID font "Arial".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Arial, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from %rom%Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Identity ... Done.
Can't find CID font "Verdana".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Verdana, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
```

Is there any parameter to solve my problem with those fonts ?. Thank you.

PS: If you want to test the original PDF file, you can download it here : [PDF File](https://mega.nz/#!2fYy3AIA!OFXfCB9AN2j1hWzmAeWt7kNzhmw92vwwby78O54KafU)

Answer (score 1):

Your PDF file uses the following CIDFonts; Arial, Arial,Bold, Verdana, Verdana,Bold and Verdana,BoldItalic. It does not include **any** of these fonts.

While it is poor practice not to include regular fonts, it is specifically stated in the specification that CIDFonts must be embedded. However, many creators fail to do so, presumably because it's comparatively hard. Much easier to include a reference and leave the hard work to the PDF consumer. So what if the font isn't available to the consumer....

If the font or CIDFont is not present Ghostscript must use a substitute. CIDFonts are harder to substitute for than regular Fonts, and Ghostscript ships with basically one real substitute CIDFont, DroidSansFallback, which it uses for all languages. There is a 'bullet' CIDFont which is the ultimate last-ditch fallback, as it contains nothing except a bullet glyph.

To get the correct output you must either embed the CIDFonts in the PDF file, or supply a suitable substitute CIDFont for Ghostscript to use. Note that the `FONTPATH` switch only applies to **fonts**, not CIDFonts, so it will not be useful for this file (though it may have benefits for files using fonts, obviously).

The CIDFont substitution mechanism is described in the Ghostscript [documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.27/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution). I imagine that if you supply the various Windows TrueType fonts to Ghostscript as substitutes for the missing named CIDFonts then your file will render correctly.

Note that, since you are using Windows, Ghostscript will be using a ROM file system. If you edit the cidfmap file you will need to use the `-I` (Include) switch to add the path containing the cidfmap file to the search path. You may find it easier to simply edit the file in c:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.27\Resource\Init and add that enter path using `-I"c:/Program Files (x86)/gs/gs9.27/Resource/Init"`.

Comment: Thanks. Ghostscript should solve that, all the viewers I have tried have no problems detecting that there is a system font with the same name and using it. The CDIFont substitution mechanism to TrueType doesn't seem to work for me, I guess that's because I have no idea what must go to /SubfontID and /CSI. I will keep trying, my boss won't allow me to embed the fonts (a x6 size increase) just to be able to use Ghostscript.  :-(

Comment: Its not 'just to be able to use Ghostscript'. Any viewer which does not have the CIDFonts available will need to use a substittue font. Since these are Windows fonts, that means any non-Windows platofrm. SO you are significantly reducing the portability by not embedding the fonts. Who cares about file size these days anyway ? As for 'Ghostscript should solve that'. It can't. For the same reason you can't. There's no way to guess what the values for the TrueType fonts hsould be. Ghostscript is cross-platofmr, so we can't simply make assumptions about the OS we're running on.